# Magento 2.3.0 How to add review form in custom module?

Tags: module, frontend, magento2.3, product-review

I would like to add a review form in my custom module front end page. On this page, I have displayed several selected products.

I want to display a review form in front of each product each review form on my custom page.

Please see the below attached screenshot for better understand.

[image]

How can I achieve these things? Make sure each product have a separate review form and it should be default Magento review form.

---

**Edit :**

> app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

```
<div>
     <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Review\Block\Form")->setTemplate('Namespace_ModuleName::form.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

Using **create a block and set template** method I am able to display review form. but I am getting trouble in submitting the form. because In my custom review page form action parameter is not passing the product ID.

The current review form action is like

> /review/product/post/

What actually review form action (It should be like below).

> /review/product/post/id/14/

Why ID is not passing in the form action. Is it a wrong method to display review form? or is there any other way to display review form?

---

**Update :**

After creating a custom block and extend my block to `\Magento\Review\Block\Form`(default) then I am able to see product ID in form action URL.

> app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

```
<div>
     <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock("Namespace\ModuleName\Block\ReviewForm")->setTemplate('Namespace_ModuleName::form.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

Now I can see separate review form for a separate product. But in console, I am getting an error like below.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Because of the above error, I am not able to submit a review for all product. can anyone help me to solve out this problem?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have not added jsLayout in argument data. Since you have created block in php file, you may have following code in your module's di.xml file.

> [Vendor][Module]\etc\di.xml

```
<type name="[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\ReviewForm">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="review-form" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Review/js/view/review</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Add this code and it should work.

Comment: Hahahaha... Fab!!!! Man. It's working.

Comment: @Yash Shah please answer this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279918/how-to-add-a-additional-field-in-summary-section-magento-2-3

Answer (score 0):

Can any one suggest. how to place review form in the Items Ordered (sales/order/view/order_id)