# How to add a additional field in Summary Section magento 2.3

Tags: cart, magento2.3, checkout-summary

My Actual Screen look like
[image]
I Expexted Result look like
[image: requirement model screenshot]

How to Display Total Savings like above mentioned screenshot.

I need to print **Sum of total added product savings amount**  in summary section

Comment: If you add anything here, it will add up in order total, and you just need to show it here without any addition

Comment: Currently there is no Field "Total Savings " in summery Section

Comment: You can use this module for reference. And change a few things logically as per your need. https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-extrafee

Comment: Can you show complete code of the module which adds that column? Or is it just a regular Magento discount?

Comment: $savings=($_item->getProduct()->getPrice()-$_item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice())*$block->getQty(); this code i use to display savings individually. all others are by default magneto features